# Speeding up this NIntegrate

Tags: numerical-integration, performance-tuning

I'm trying out the code below and it takes quite a long time to compute and throws eincr and slwcon warnings. Is there a way to speed this up?

```
phase[u_, m_, \[Theta]_, \[Phi]_] := 
  u^3 + 2 m \[Theta] (3/(4 m))^(2/3) Cos[\[Phi]] u^2 + 
   m \[Theta]^2 (3/(4 m))^(1/3) u - m \[Theta] Cos[\[Phi]];

integrand[u_, 
   m_, \[Theta]_, \[Phi]_] := (-2 (3/(4 m))^(1/3)
       u + \[Theta] ) Exp[-I phase[u, m, \[Theta], \[Phi]]];

integral[\[Theta]_, \[Phi]_, m_, {ulo_, uhi_}] := 
 NIntegrate[integrand[u, m, \[Theta], \[Phi]], {u, ulo, uhi}, 
   MaxRecursion -> 20, WorkingPrecision -> 20] // 
  Timing

integraltab = 
  Monitor[Table[{\[Theta], \[Phi], 
     integral[\[Theta], \[Phi], 100, {-Infinity, Infinity}]}, {\[Theta], 0, 
     Pi, Pi/32}, {\[Phi], 0, 2 Pi, 
     2 Pi/63}], {\[Theta], \[Phi]}];
```

Comment: Do all 2000+ integrals have the same problem? Or can you narrow down the problem to test case one could start with?

Comment: @MichaelE2 For the first couple of values of theta, it's fairly fast. After that, it's really slow.

Answer (score 1):

The integrand only depends on  `Cos[\[Phi]`, that's why you can decrease the integration range to  `{\[Phi], 0,  Pi}` (- 50% evaluation time!)!

Include the option `Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}` inside `NIntegrate`:

```
integral[\[Theta]_, \[Phi]_, m_, {ulo_, uhi_}] := 
NIntegrate[integrand[u, m, \[Theta], \[Phi]], {u, ulo, uhi} ,MaxRecursion -> 20, WorkingPrecision -> 20 
,Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}]
```

the grid of 101x101 tablevalues is evaluated in nearly 75s!

```
integraltab = Monitor[Table[{\[Theta], \[Phi],integral[\[Theta], \[Phi],100, {-Infinity, Infinity}]}
, {\[Theta], 0, Pi,Pi/10}, {\[Phi], 0,  Pi, Pi/10}], {\[Theta], \[Phi]}]; // Timing
(*{74.7813, Null}*)
```

Without these modifictions the evaluation of 101x101 grid lasts around  1700s ( **speedup  factor 23** ) !

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you, but I actually need it over 2 Pi since I'll later integrate this over a sphere.

Comment: No problem, because  `Cos[2Pi-phi]==Cos[Phi]`.

Comment: … Without this symmetrie evaluation time still would be 12times faster!